# Numbers Formula Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers

I am currently doing a spreadsheet that uses a tick box to add VAT if necessary (therefore multiply the figure by 1.2)?

I have tried adding a value of TRUE or 1 to the tick box but I still get a syntax issue

```
=IF((D2,TRUE),(B2×C2×1.2),B2×C2)
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated in making this make sense!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
=B2*C2*IF(D2,1.2,1)
```

You will need to make sure your checkbox has a *cell link*. Right click on the checkbox and *Format Control*. On the *Control* tab you will see *Cell Link*. That's the cell that will be `TRUE` or `FALSE` when the checkbox is selected/unselected, respectively, so that needs to be the cell that you refer to here as `D2`. You might want to move it elsewhere, like `H2`.

---

*Extra info*...

Since the format of the `IF` function is

```
=IF(expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

and `D2` (the expression) will either be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you don't need to do `D2=TRUE`. Just `D2` will suffice.